# Receive email intent of WhatsApp's "Send chat by email" option

Tags: java, android, email, whatsapp

I want to give the user the option to import the his WhatsApp chats in my app. The chats can be exported in WhatsApp as Txt-File sent in an email as attachment with the option "Send chat by email". The problem is, I don't know how to receive the Intent WhatsApp is sending to get avaivable email apps. The java code is already finished, but in the AndroidManifest.xml file I dont know what to write to be known as email app.
**Edit**
I don't want to send E-Mails, but I want that the user has the possibility to import Chat-Data for the chatbot App I am programming.

Comment: Hm, sounds like you are trying to trick users into handing private data over to your app. That is something the android system will block for very good reasons... You'd have to register your app as the primary email sending service, obviously. But I doubt any user will consent with that...

Comment: no i am programming a chat bot. the chat data can be imported as "knowledge"

Comment: Sorry, can't follow you. You say you can _not_ import. So what do you mean by "can be imported as knowledge"?

Comment: Your app intercepting a legitimate call of another app to send data via email is a _clear_ violation of the privacy principles, _unless_ the user clearly authorized your app to do so.

Comment: Ehh we say he clicks on send via email Option on WhatsApp. Then he can choose Gmail,... And "import Chat as knowledge for bot..." When the User clicks that he has to confirm it again and If he does so, it Imports. The cannot do this without knowing it. I don't know what you want to tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to list your app as an option to receive [`Intent.ACTION_SEND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND), you have to do:
1: Register your app as an e-Mail client, you can use `Gmail API` from Google to send and receive e-Mails.
2: Use `intent-filter` in your `Mainifest.xml` as

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
```

Simple tutorial at: [Android Developer | Receiveing simple data](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)

 Since WhatsApp sends chats as a `.txt` attachment, so you need to register for that `data-type` in your `intent-filter` too.